# how to insert new div generated by javascript into existing one?

Tags: javascript, html

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 for (var i = 0; i < surveyResults.resultsOfSurvey.length; i = i + 1) {
                        debugger;

                        var answer = surveyResults.resultsOfSurvey[i].correct;
                        var qId = surveyResults.resultsOfSurvey[i].id;
                        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
                        newElement.id = surveyResults[i];
                        newElement.className = "answer";
                        newElement.innerHTML = "Antwort ist: " + answer + "! Fragen ID ist: " + qId + ".";
                        document.body.appendChild(newElement);

                    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contentForSurvey">

        <div id="answers"></div>
```

How do I insert a div from my `for` loop into the div with `id="answers"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
document.getElementById("answers").appendChild(newElement);
```

Instead of `document.body.appendChild(newElement);`